# Configure ubuntu to record every keystroke in every session

Tags: keyboard

I want to get my computer, with ubuntu 16.04, to record every keystroke in every session and store it in a text file. With "every keystroke" I do not mean every keystroke in terminal, because I've already found answers to that, and it's not what I'm looking for.

So, having physical acces to the computer and sudo privileges, is it possible to achieve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found it myself and it's pretty simple.
To do this you have to

- Install and configure logkey (`sudo apt-get install logkeys`).
- Set the startup command for logkeys (with keymap and output file) to run in /etc/rc.local.
- Then just reboot and see.

Comment: `logkeys` is not in the repository (Ubuntu 20.04). I had to install from source: [instructions](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys/blob/master/INSTALL)